# How can I add a "new" icon or text, right to a call string wen new array is added in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, string, echo

i need to display new icon or some text just right the call string wen every time new array id is added for a defined amount of time
ex: i need to make that icon visible 5 days after array id is added

my array is this:

```
<?php 
$vidooidepsub = array(
  "nullid", 
  "title 1", 
  "title 2",
  "title 3", 
  "title 4",
  "title 5"
);
?>
```

and i call the array last id (title) like this:

```
<?php echo end($vidooidepsub); ?>
```

the output is this: `title 5`

what i need is adding a icon right to output title of a specific time, and wen the new array id is added before expire time make that time counts from the start

(thx and sorry for my bad inglish)

Comment: Create two variables: lastId, expiryTime. Whenever you add new id to array store it in the lastId variable and change the expiryTime to new DateTime("+5 days"). Then in your echo statement check whether end($vidooidepsub) == $lastId

Comment: @user2463644 i dont know how to create the entire code you commented , if you help me with 50% i can do the rest

Comment: $vidooidepsub[] = "title 6"; $lastId = "title 6"; $expiryTime = new DateTime("+5 days");

Comment: i changed the code now the problem were to add expirtion time variabale <?php $vidooidepsub[] = $lastId;?> <?php $lastId= end($vidooidepsub);?> $expiryTime = new DateTime("+4 days");

Comment: Reset expiryTime when the new id is added to array

Comment: @user2463644 yes i know, but where i put the $expirtiontime string

Comment: @user2463644   like this ?:   <?php $expiryTime= new DateTime("+4 days");?>
  <?php $vidooidepsub[$expiryTime] = $lastId;?> <?php $lastId= end($vidooidepsub);?>

Comment: You put it right after you add new id to array: $vidooidepsub[] = "title 6"; $expiryTime = new DateTime("+5 days");

Comment: @user2463644 yes but array id`s are in other file, only i have problems in call actions

Comment: Then put it in the same file where array is